# ionic $http cannot access shopify

Tags: jquery, cordova, ionic-framework, shopify

I am building a restaurant app using ionic and i need to access the data from the shopify api. how can i access the data from the shopify api?

```
$http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/customers.json',
          header: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"}
    }).then(function(resp) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(resp));
  }, function(err) {
    alert("err"+JSON.stringify(err));
    // err.status will contain the status code
  })
```

in some forums , i have got the above code for http request.but the above code returns an error status:0. Please help.

Comment: It sounds like CORS is not enabled on the myshopify.com domain. Your use of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is moot, as it must be set by the server to allow access, not the client.

Comment: In addition to what @RoryMcCrossan said, you may have to pass along an `Authorization` header of some sort with your request. I'm not familiar with the shopify API requirements, but its a common practice.

Comment: @SteamDev I believe that's what the OP has blocked out with `x` characters in the subdomain part of the URL.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the above url, if entered into browser, it will return a json data.. but i cannot access it through ionic..

Comment: It sounds like you may be being blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). If this is the case, you will need to make the request server side.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok..i have an store.myshopify.com and i have the storefront as anothersite.com . how can i make the app access the data?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is a CORS issue like stated in the comments.
If you're developing in Google Chrome, you could use handy extension which allows you to change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` setting.

This allows you to retrieve the data in your app.

Here's the link:
[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * - Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

This will display a red(disabled) or green(enabled) button in the top right corner of your browser.

*Sidenote:* Make sure this extension is only enabled when developing your application. Otherwise this could result in undesirable behaviour on other websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can only fetch data like this if your are on same server means this code will work only inside the same store you are fetch data for.
To fetch data from different store, you need to follow https://docs.shopify.com/api/introduction/getting-started steps mentioned on this URL.